# How can $\tan x > 2$ be solved?

Tags: trigonometry

We have this inequality:
$$1<\tan x<2$$

The first part can easily be solved. However, I can't see how you can solve the 2nd part ($>2$) without a calculator.
My first idea was to substract $1$ from each side, but you get
$$0< \tan x - 1 < 1,$$ so the form isn't right.

Comment: https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-find-the-exact-value-of-arctan-2

Comment: What is wrong with an answer involving "$\arctan 2$"?

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? The solution to $\tan x = 2$ does not have a nice form. You can find a decimal  approximation as accurate as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \tan(x)$ is continuous on the open interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. Hence its inverse maps open intervals to open intervals. So your question is: what is $f^{-1}((1,2))$? Since $f$ is increasing, the solution is $(\tan^{-1}(1), \tan^{-1}(2)) = (\pi/4, \tan^{-1}(2))$.

Since $f(x + k \pi) = f(x)$ for all integers $k$, all the solutions are those $x$ of the form $x= a+ k\pi$, where $a \in (\pi/4, \tan^{-1}(2))$.

Comment: Note that $\tan^{-1}(1)=\frac{\pi}4$.

Comment: @Soheil0098 Thanks !